# Convert manually entered PHP timezone to a "valid" one

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

We have an application which allows users to enter their timezone manually (via a regular text box). 
Since I don't think this was a good idea, I was thinking about replacing this mechanism by showing a drop-down list which lists all of the supported PHP timezones (by using `DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()`).

However, I am not sure how to convert the user input (like 'GMT', or other timezones listed here: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php) to a timezone which is listed as a result of the listIdentifiers() function.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. First you're writing that you have a text input and want to replace it with selectbox but finally you want to convert the value from text input? :p

If you have a value from selectbox with proper identifier you can just create a new DateTimeZone object with name as argument like this:

```
new DateTimeZone($str);
```

After that you can do anything with it.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. As of now, users have already inserted their timezones manually, but I would like to take their input and 'convert' them to a value which can be mapped to the new timezone, so it will appear in the drop-down correctly.

Comment: Well the only solution I see here is to pass the string they have entered to DateTimeZone constructor in try .. catch block and on exception (if zone doesnt exist) just set the default one or set null.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out, and I also found "DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC" which I can use. Thanks! :)